# Disney buys all the rights on sex bots

Tags: internal-consistency, society, technology, robots, future

Year 2030, and sex bots have now been around since the early 2018 and existed as a concept for more than half a century.

But during the last years they became more and more common, they are not in every house like a computer yet but more companies were manufacturing sex bots were born.

However Disney decided to buy all sex bot manufacturers and copyright them.

How can Disney make money or use them to gain power without ruining their reputation?

Sex bots technology:

They are like any self learning AI of the present day (2020)

they start off making no sense and learn like children. The more you speak to them and the more they learn to talk like real humans until they scare you by becoming smarter than normal people and you start feeling guilty the days you don't talk to them or when you turn off the device.

(at least that's my experience talking with bots)

Comment: That's not how copyright works; you cannot "copyright" an idea, or a process, or a design. You may have wanted to say "patented", but then this cannot be because you say that sex bots had already been around for some time. Realistically, what Disney can do is use *trademark* law to protect some brands of sex bots; which will help with the luxury market, but little else.

Comment: That's simple, Disney creates a new child company, that child company handles the bots, Disney does not publicize to the world, that they own it, So most of the general public never got to know, never cared.

Comment: The Walt Disney Company owns, for example, 20th Century Studios, the output of which is not really consonant with what we usually expect from Disney... See [*Deep Water*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Water_(2020_film)), [*The Woman in the Window*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Woman_in_the_Window_(2020_film)), or [*The Empty Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Empty_Man_(film)) (all made or being made *after* the acquisition by Disney).

Comment: @AlexP Apple suing Disney for sexbots with rounded corners :grin:

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Apple changing the "ports" on their sexbots to be incompatible with existing genitals...

Comment: Touchstone Pictures is a fully-owned subsidiary of the Walt Disney company, and they made (among other films) _Starship Troopers_, featuring full frontal nudity.  They're no strangers to prurience, and Touchstone was created to release PG-13 and R-rated films without using the Disney name.

Comment: Um. It's a sex bot. Why would a user want to talk to it to the point it becomes smarter than the user? (Not that the AI would have to expend much effort, mind!) Doesn't this rather defeat the purpose of the bot?

Comment: @elemtilas  look up the word "sapiosexual"

Comment: @elemtilas Surely the type to own a sex bot would also want to replace human interactions with it, maybe some people like a challenge and want to be nagged like a real wife by their sex bot lol.

Comment: So many layers of ewwwwww in this question.

Answer (score 4):

Strangely enough if you google human-like robotics "companionship" robots are some of the most developed, I guess necessity from the designers and profits from the manufacturers pushes innovation into making a life-life experience.

But as the comments mention, Disney can't own the rights to sex bots, they might own patents to some of technologies and design but those could easily be replicated and improved by others.

They could easily split the company into robotic toys (like a cuddly toy but far more advanced), helper robots for the elderly and disabled, still keep the companionship robot branch and if the technology is advanced enough AI could basically be the beginning of all automated aspects in life, but they wont be able to control the whole market over longer periods of time without using force.

Comment: Sex and the military are the two primary "early adopter" industries, the rise of home video players being a classic example of the former, so don't be surprised about them being ahead of the game on this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

welcome to Worldbuilding SE. Here's the problem: physical products and, most important, technology don't really work via copyright on a normal basis, they work mainly via patents. So rather than trying to track down "copyright violations" of these robots, Disney would have to be constantly stalking the patents of all components that make their production possible so that they don't get stolen by others, while also forbidding everyone from using said components. Problem is: the opposing companies would likely just try to [work their way around it](https://www.forbes.com/sites/stephenkey/2018/11/30/the-best-way-to-protect-your-invention-try-stealing-it-from-yourself/#1e1f370d71ee) and the old patents could even risk becoming obsolete, meaning all that work would be for nothing. Remember Disney can't really copyright the concept of sexbot (think of all the existing variations of the Airfryer).

So how can Disney both get a hold of the sexbot market and protect its family-friendly status? Well that's "easy": don't buy the sexbots, buy the companies that make them.

Rather than take the sexbot technology and control the market with your name until new bots appear, why not use someone else's? Disney would have a much easier time tracking down the stocks of the main sexbot companies and buying as much of those as they can (that is, if they can't buy the companies themselves, thus having complete control over them). That way, they'll have a good control over well known companies and their already established market, profiting from the biggest heads of the sexbot industry without using your child-friendly-brand name. Additionally, playing your cards right, you can use the bigger companies to compete with the smaller ones, weakening them and allowing Disney to buy them as well, now at a lower price than what you'd pay if you bought them before such measures.

Summing up: instead of buying the rights to make the bots, buy the already established companies which make them. Disney is already doing this, just not focusing on the porn industry (as far as I know, at least). By keeping an eye out and buying those or by getting a hold of most of their stocks, especially in an eventual moment they might be cheaper for some reason (which should be more than worth the price if Disney is willing to take the entire sexbot market to itself), Disney will get a hold over already established companies, acting like nothing has changed and thus being able to enjoy the pre-established consumers which like these companies. After that, they can likely just smash the competition altogether or buy them as well once they're about to close, profiting from them and essentially monopolizing the sexbot market. Even if more people were to find out (which wouldn't be that hard) that Disney owns all of these companies, I doubt they'd care much about it. Disney just happened to buy these guys to profit from their activities, which doesn't mean Disney as a brand would be immediately treated as porn-oriented or no longer family-friendly. Disney is still Disney, "Botlover" Is still "Botlover", it just happens that one owns the other now.

Comment: You basically just described the cosmetics industry. It's possible to walk down some aisles in a pharmacy and encounter nothing but Glaxo-Smith-Kline products under various different 'competing' brand names.

Answer (score 2):

Frame challenge: like others pointed out, Disney can't own the rights to sex dolls as a concept, but they can force everyone else out of the market until they are the only big name.

A subsidiary of Disney can be set up that makes use of their massive financial backing and army of lawyers to dominate the sex doll industry, while maintaining enough of a separation to avoid tainting Disney's name.

Starting off by buying up patents relating to sex dolls and not allowing other companies to use the technology would give them a head start, but doesn't stop other companies from innovating their way around it. Owning a set of vague patents, combined with the threat of being sued by Disney's subsidiary, would be fairly effective in stopping small companies popping up to try and take advantage of the market. While Disney would most likely lose the case if it went to court, the fact that small companies wouldn't be able to afford a lengthy legal battle would be enough to deter a lot of people (while this strategy has been used in the past, I don't know enough about modern US IP law to say if its still a viable strategy. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong in the comments).

On top of that, undercutting other companies and selling your products at a loss for an extended period to force competitors in to bankruptcy is going to make sure you have an almost complete monopoly on the market. Once the companies start struggling, buy them up and their patents. As long as you are backed by Disney, you can keep this up indefinitely.

Lobbying the government to enact overly stringent regulations on sex dolls could also help by putting a big hurdle in place for any new manufacturer.

On top of that, having exclusive deals with retailers and heavy advertising campaigns makes sure that you're the only product a consumer sees.

Finally, and probably most importantly, is to maintain a strong relationship with the government. Having large manufacturing plants in key voting districts always helps, as no politician wants to do anything that might jeopardize their chances of reelection if you have to close factories.
Being seen as a 'strategic necessity' to national security is a time tested approach for this- having the subsidiary develop AI chips needed by the military in addition to sex bots is one way of making sure you're 'too big to fail'.

Answer (score 0):

### They build a theme park, and it looks like ...

... [the HBO series West World.](https://www.hbo.com/westworld/season-01)

While you don't have to take your narrative into the corporate competition and conspiracy theory direction that the TV series did, an adults-only Disneyland theme park with various worlds (wild west, medieval Japan, dystopian future, Arabian Nights, Roman orgies, what have you) are each a plausible setting to put sex bots into for a profit based entertainment venue.

One of the key features of the West World style of bots and sex bots is the "dialable" personality features.  This would allow the kind of 'social learning' you are referring to in the question.  (Heck, it's a major plot point of the series).